# Jquery hover effect for each row in php query

Tags: php, jquery

For starters, here is my php:

```
$id2 = mysql_real_escape_string($id2);
                $getdata8 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM musicbook WHERE identify='$identify' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20");
                $numrowsgetdata = mysql_num_rows($getdata8);
                if ((mysql_num_rows($getdata8))<1)
                {
                echo "<i>Be the first to say something?</i><p/>"; 
                }
                while ($row8 = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata8))
                {
                $id8 = $row8['id'];
                $name8 = $row8['name'];
                $message8 = $row8['message'];
                $message10 = nl2br($message8);
                $date8 = $row8['date'];
                if ($name8==$username)
                {
                echo "
                <div class='messagediv' style='background:#1A1A1A;'><div style='padding:5px;'>$message10<br/>
                <div style='margin-top:4px; font-size:.8em; float:left;'><div style='float:left;'><a href='http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/$name8' style='color:white;'>$name8</a><font style='color:#D6D6D6'> on $date8</font></div>
                <input type='hidden' id='wpm2' value='$id8'><input type='button' id='deletelistenchat' class='deletelistenchat' style='display:none;' onclick='LinkOnClick2($id8); loadlistenchat();' value='(delete?)' /></div></div></div>
                ";
                }
                else
                {
                echo "
                <div class='messagediv'><div style='padding:5px;'>$message10<br/>
                <div style='margin-top:4px; font-size:.8em; float:left;'><div style='float:left;'><a href='http://www.pearlsquirrel.com/$name8' style='color:white;'>$name8</a><font style='color:#D6D6D6'> on $date8</font></div>
                </div></div></div>";
                }
                }
                if($numrowsgetdata >= 20)
                {
                echo "<div id='loadingcomments'><img src='loading.gif' style='height:30px; width:30px;'></div>";
                }
                ?>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$('.messagediv').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    document.getElementById('deletelistenchat').style.display='block';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('deletelistenchat').style.display='none';
    }
    });
```

Now what I want to happen is that for each .messagediv div when you hover over it, it shows the delete button, #deletelistenchat.  However, it only works for the last row of each mysql query and I want the hover effect to work on each one as a user hover over it.  For example, if I hover over the first post by a user, the hover effect activates on the last post retrieved by the mysql query.  I have been trying to figure this out for some time now, and am lost as anything.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: btw. jquery.live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7

Comment: And JavaScript (and therefore all the JavaScript libraries, including jQuery, though with the exception of [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/)) works on the client-side, not the server. So your PHP is irrelevant to the question, we need to see your HTML (as seen by the browser) to offer specifically useful assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's are unique. You are using the same ID over and over, because of this, the DOM is only finding the last element with that ID -- that's the intended effect, it's a result of how you wrote your php.

`<input type='button' id='deletelistenchat'`

Remove the ID from this button. You already have the class here.

let's change your hover event.

```
$(function(){
  $('.messagediv').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('.deletelistenchat').css('display', 'block');
  }).on('mouseout', function(){
    $(this).find('.deletelistenchat').css('display', 'none');
  });
});
```

`*Edit*`

DOM Behavior wasn't functioning as expected because I didn't clearly look at your markup, that's my fault. Made it jQuery 1.7 worthy, and separated your mouseover and mouseout statements to be able to clearly see them.

The working Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/6MpX9/

Comment: Using the above, what's the issue you are encountering?

Comment: The deletelistenchat button is not appearing on hover of .messagediv, and I have done exactly what you recommended above.